# systemd service script breaks boot process

Tags: scripts, systemd

I have a script that is part of the systemd service that will start on boot.

```bsh
while true
do
 …
 content
 …
  sleep 30
 fi
done
```

but a line `sleep 30` breaks the boot process,
how to start this service and continue to boot without pause ?

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please include your `.service` file so we can see the before and after services. Why does your script need to sleep for 30 seconds?

Comment: systemd will wait for oneshot services to end execution. Use some other type.